# Is it possible to apply when.otherwise functions within agg after a groupBy?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Been recently trying to apply a default function to aggregated values that were being calculated so that I didn't have to reprocess them afterwards. As far as I see I'm getting the following error.

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported`

From the following function.

```
    val defaultUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf[Column, Column, Any](defaultFunction)
    def defaultFunction(col: Column, value: Any): Column = {
      when(col.equalTo(value), null).otherwise(col)
    }
```

And applying it the following way.

```
    val initialDF = Seq(
      ("a", "b", 1),
      ("a", "b", null),
      ("a", null, 0)
    ).toDF("field1", "field2", "field3")

    initialDF
      .groupBy("field1", "field2")
      .agg(
        defaultUDF(functions.count("field3"), lit(0)).as("counter") // exception thrown here
      )
```

Am I trying to do black magic in here or is it something that I may be missing?

Comment: Drop the UDF and it will work just fine.

Comment: @user10938362 there has to be a reason why that ain't working with a UDF and without does...? And still, without it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the implementation of your `UserDefinedFunction`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

def defaultFunction(col: Column, value: Any): Column = {
  when(col.equalTo(value), null).otherwise(col)
}

val defaultUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf[Column, Column, Any](defaultFunction)
// java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported
//   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:789)
//   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:724)
//   at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
//   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:906)
//   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:46)
//   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:723)
//   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:720)
//   at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3914)
//   ... 65 elided
```

The error you're getting is basically because Spark cannot map the return type (i.e. `Column`) of your  `UserDefinedFunction` `defaultFunction` to a Spark DataType. 
Your defaultFunction has to accept and return Scala types that correspond with a Spark DataType. You can find the list of supported Scala types here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference.html#data-types

In any case, you don't need a `UserDefinedFunction` if your function takes Columns and returns a Column. For your use-case, the following code will work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Record(field1: String, field2: String, field3: java.lang.Integer)

val df = Seq(
  Record("a", "b", 1),
  Record("a", "b", null),
  Record("a", null, 0)
).toDS

df.show

// +------+------+------+
// |field1|field2|field3|
// +------+------+------+
// |     a|     b|     1|
// |     a|     b|  null|
// |     a|  null|     0|
// +------+------+------+

def defaultFunction(col: Column, value: Any): Column = {
  when(col.equalTo(value), null).otherwise(col)
}

df
.groupBy("field1", "field2")
.agg(defaultFunction(count("field3"), lit(0)).as("counter"))
.show

// +------+------+-------+                                                         
// |field1|field2|counter|
// +------+------+-------+
// |     a|     b|      1|
// |     a|  null|      1|
// +------+------+-------+
```